# how to sum row according to multiple column values and keep other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following columns

```
Index(['TNVED', 'Product_Name', 'Export_Value', 'Import_Value', 'Year',
       'Country', 'Region', 'Total_Export_XLS', 'Total_Import_XLS',
       'Export_Sum', 'Import_Sum'],
```

I want to sum cells  of columns `'Export_Value', 'Import_Value'` when values of `'TNVED', 'Product_Name', 'Year', 'Country', 'Region'` columns are the same.

```
df = df.groupby(['TNVED', 'Product_Name',  'Year', 'Country', 'Region'], as_index = False).agg({'Export_Value': "sum",  'Import_Value': 'sum',  'Total_Export_XLS': 'first', 'Total_Import_XLS':'first'})
```

but this code destroyed my previous groupping(According to TNVED, YEAR, Region). 
How can I handle this task saving the current groupping and only sum rows where above mentioned column values are same?

[image: I have filtered this data using Excel]
My intention is to sum two(and keep only resulted row) similar rows according to the above-mentioned column names.

2. This summing process has to be done only if TNVED number is 999999. Hope this narrowing helps to save current groupby

Also tried this code and unfortunately, this also destroying my current groupping

```
cols = ['Export_Value', 'Import_Value']
df1[cols] = df1.groupby(['TNVED',   'Year', 'Country', 'Region'], as_index = False)[cols].transform('sum')
```

I tried to regroup resulted in dataframe however

```
#df = df.groupby(['TNVED', 'Year', 'Region'])
```

However, after this code, my data frame decreased by almost 6 times.

So my task is first to sum rows and keep resulted then regroup resulted dataframe by `['TNVED','Year', 'Region']`

Comment: What is your input & expected out, include that in your post.

Comment: dont save back to original dataframe, use a new variable

Comment: @Sushanth updated

Comment: Could you please add source data as text, as well as expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a crack at interpreting what you want here.

df

```
      TNVED  Export_Value  Import_Value  Year  Country  Region
0  0.092334      0.832676      0.690358  2008   Russia    Asia
1  0.415750      0.869601      0.007326  2008   Russia    Asia
2  0.869288      0.647665      0.501672  2009  Ukraine  Europe
3  0.847242      0.158745      0.640460  2009  Ukraine  Europe
4  0.520464      0.847487      0.347874  2010   Poland  Europe
5  0.998990      0.727221      0.421134  2010   Poland  Europe
6  0.689616      0.203462      0.315914  2011   Poland  Europe
7  0.318693      0.333828      0.447039  2011   Poland  Europe
```

Add an extra column for your net export value calculation, and set it to NaN

```
df['Net_Exports'] = np.nan

      TNVED  Export_Value  Import_Value  Year  Country  Region  Net_Exports
0  0.092334      0.832676      0.690358  2008   Russia    Asia          NaN
1  0.415750      0.869601      0.007326  2008   Russia    Asia          NaN
2  0.869288      0.647665      0.501672  2009  Ukraine  Europe          NaN
3  0.847242      0.158745      0.640460  2009  Ukraine  Europe          NaN
4  0.520464      0.847487      0.347874  2010   Poland  Europe          NaN
5  0.998990      0.727221      0.421134  2010   Poland  Europe          NaN
6  0.689616      0.203462      0.315914  2011   Poland  Europe          NaN
7  0.318693      0.333828      0.447039  2011   Poland  Europe          NaN
```

If the TNVED value is equal to 999999 (here I use a threshold value since you didn't provide raw data, so I used random number generation for dummy data, and thus a threshold) then group for addition operation. Sorry if this adds confusion, next time provide your data sample and your desired result to avoid such things.

```
TNVED_THRESHOLD = 0.2    
df['Net_Exports'] = df[df['TNVED'] > TNVED_THRESHOLD].groupby(['Year', 'Country', 'Region'], as_index=False).transform(lambda x: x.sum())

      TNVED  Export_Value  Import_Value  Year  Country  Region  Net_Exports
0  0.092334      0.832676      0.690358  2008   Russia    Asia          NaN
1  0.415750      0.869601      0.007326  2008   Russia    Asia     0.415750
2  0.869288      0.647665      0.501672  2009  Ukraine  Europe     1.716529
3  0.847242      0.158745      0.640460  2009  Ukraine  Europe     1.716529
4  0.520464      0.847487      0.347874  2010   Poland  Europe     1.519454
5  0.998990      0.727221      0.421134  2010   Poland  Europe     1.519454
6  0.689616      0.203462      0.315914  2011   Poland  Europe     1.008309
7  0.318693      0.333828      0.447039  2011   Poland  Europe     1.008309
```

Now drop the rows that are similar according to the groupings, keeping the first row of similar rows in groups. Now you can choose to do what you want with the TNVED != 999999 cases. Here row 0 represents this case since my threshold for TNVED was 0.2.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Net_Exports')

      TNVED  Export_Value  Import_Value  Year  Country  Region  Net_Exports
0  0.092334      0.832676      0.690358  2008   Russia    Asia          NaN
1  0.415750      0.869601      0.007326  2008   Russia    Asia     0.415750
2  0.869288      0.647665      0.501672  2009  Ukraine  Europe     1.716529
4  0.520464      0.847487      0.347874  2010   Poland  Europe     1.519454
6  0.689616      0.203462      0.315914  2011   Poland  Europe     1.008309
```